# Load a fragment in an Activity containing RecycelerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an Activity that has only a `RecycelerView`. I want to load a fragment when pressed each item of `RecycelerView` and some data should sent to my fragment.In my adapter,I write `loadFragment` function and call it in `onBindViewHolder` function.When i press the item,show fragment but my `RecycelrView` still exists and is shown.In `xml` file of`MainActivity` I put a `FrameLayout` with id `flContent` that include a `RecycelerView`.how to hide `RecycelerView` and sent data to my fragment?
this is `xml` file of `MainActivity`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/flContent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recPost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 />
 </FrameLayout>
```

this is adapter's code.

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Post> values;

public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> values) {
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyceler_post_item, parent, false);
    return new PostViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Post post=values.get(position);
    holder.txtCaption.setText(post.getCaption());
    holder.txtPreview.setText(post.getPreview());
    holder.root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFragment(holder.layoutId,new InfoPostFragment());
        }
    });
}

private void loadFragment(int layoutId, Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager =((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(layoutId, fragment).commit();
}

public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtCaption;
    private TextView txtPreview;
    private FrameLayout flContent;
    private int layoutId;
    private View root;
    public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        root=itemView;
        txtCaption=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaption);
        txtPreview=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPreview);
        flContent=itemView.findViewById(R.id.flContent);
        layoutId=R.id.flContent;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the recyclerView from FrameLayout

Pass a reference of the framelayout or just use the activity context in loadFragment to find the frameLayout and frameLayout.removeAllViews()

or just findViewById(R.android.recPost).setVisibility(View.GONE)

However one thing i would like to point out. Managing the Fragment lifecycle should be a part of the Activity file the loadFragment code should not be in your Adapter class.You might want to reconsider this approach. Implement a callback interface for the same.

Comment: If possible give me more explanation and sudo code about your approach that implement a callback interface.